# Proving the existence of a closed set

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a compact space and $f: X \to X$ be a continuous map.  Show that there is a non-empty closed set $E \subseteq X$ such that $E = f(E)$.

First, something is a bit fishy about this problem.  I think I am missing the condition that this should be Hausdorff.

My original idea is as follows.  Since $f$ is continuous, any open $U \in Y$ has $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.  So $(f^{-1}(U))^c$ is closed.  It seems like it's easy to find a closed set, but I'm not sure how to fulfill the second property.

Comment: It is a duplicate but it will take me hours to find it if I ever find it. Meanwhile, note that you want to add "nonempty" closed set. Otherwise...

Comment: Good call.  It's always those small words that make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $K_0=X$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $K_{n+1}=f[K_n]$. Now consider $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}K_n$. (You don’t need $X$ to be Hausdorff to get $E$ to be non-empty, but you do need it to ensure that $E$ is closed. Some people define *compact* to include Hausdorff; that may be why Hausdorffness isn’t mentioned in the statement of the problem.)

**Added:** You will need to assume that $X$ is Hausdorff. To see why, let $\tau$ be the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) on $\Bbb N$; then $\langle\Bbb N,\tau\rangle$ is a compact $T_1$ space, but it’s not Hausdorff. Let $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto n+1$; this map is continuous, but there is no non-empty $E\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that $f[E]=E$, even if we don’t require $E$ to be closed. To see this, let $E$ be a non-empty subset of $\Bbb N$, and let $m=\min E$; then $m\notin f[E]$, so $f[E]\ne E$.

Comment: It seems like you are leading me down the direction of the finite intersection property.  However, how do I guarantee the fact that $K_n$ is closed?

Comment: @abet: That’s where you need $X$ to be Hausdorff.

Comment: I left off non-empty when I first wrote out the question.

Comment: @abet: I assumed that you intended it; and you get it automatically from the approach that I suggested, even if $X$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Is this the idea of the nested set theorem? If these sets were nested, then $\cap_n K_n$ would be non-empty.

Comment: @abet: So prove that these sets **are** nested! :-)

Comment: I'm having a hard time convincing myself that the sets are getting smaller (thus becoming nested).

Comment: @abet: Clearly $K_1\subseteq X=K_0$. Now apply $f$ to both sides: $K_2=f[K_1]\subseteq f[K_0]=K_1$. In general, if $K_{n+1}\subseteq K_n$, then $K_{n+2}=f[K_{n+1}]\subseteq f[K_n]=K_{n+1}$, and the result follows by induction.

Comment: To guarantee that each $K_i$ are closed, do I need to assume they are the complement of an open set.  I guess I'm still not sure why Hausdorff is not necessary.

Comment: @abet: $f$ is continuous, so if $K_n$ is compact, then so is $K_{n+1}=f[K_n]$; since $K_0=X$ is compact, all of the $K_n$ are compact. Now you need to assume that $X$ is Hausdorff: a compact set in a Hausdorff space is necessarily closed. (This is something that you should try to prove, if you’ve not already seen a proof.)

Comment: I have that theorem, that a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is again compact.  However, my definition of compactness is simply a set whose cover has a finite subcover is compact.  This is why I believe there is an error since there was no mention of the Hausdorff property on Y, for example, let Y be a compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: @abet: No, the theorem in question is that a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is **closed**. A companion theorem is that a closed subset of a compact space is compact (even if the space is not Hausdorff), but we don’t need that one. And you will need to assume that $X$ is Hausdorff, because the theorem is false otherwise. The cofinite topology on $\Bbb N$ is compact, the map $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto n+1$ is continuous, and the intersection of the sets $K_n$ in this space is empty.